# parallel access to file

Tags: c#, tcp

everyone. I'm gonna write code editor, kind of Google documents. 
I'm planning to make client - directly code editor and server. So, when user writes or removes something of opened file, the changes immediately fix onto server. Then, another used, who is connected to server, can immediately watch the changes.
The question is how to make the parallel access.

I see the next way. Transfer the file by TCP\IP protocol to the , then store it into RAM, and get access to the file from different computers. One computer to write changes, another one - to read. 
Will it work like that?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: As with all programming efforts, start with the requirements. "Parallel access" is a very ambiguous requirement by itself, plus I'm not sure it's what you mean (you seem to be describing multi-user, serial access in your post).

Comment: I didn't code anything yet. I just wanna understand how it works and then do it

Comment: This is far too broad.  This is almost, but not quite, "How do I do this?"

Comment: Look into websockets if you are planning on this being browser based.  Websockets could be used to implement what you are describing very easily.